# Regular expression match a-alphanumeric&b-digits&c-digits

Tags: java, regex

I have query about java regular expressions. Actually, I am new to regular expressions.
So I need help to form a regex for the statement below:

```
                 Statement: a-alphanumeric&b-digits&c-digits
Possible matching Examples: 1) a-90485jlkerj&b-34534534&c-643546
                            2) A-RT7456ffgt&B-86763454&C-684241
```

Use case: First of all I have to validate input string against the regular expression. If the input string matches then I have to extract **a value, b value and c value** like
**90485jlkerj, 34534534 and 643546** respectively.

Could someone please share how I can achieve this in the best possible way?

I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Instead of asking people to code your regular expressions for you, try reading the Java Regular Expressions Tutorial.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a string with the format `a-XXX&b-XXX&c-XXX`, you can extract all `XXX` parts in one simple line:

```
String[] parts = str.replaceAll("[abc]-", "").split("&");
```

`parts` will be an array with 3 elements, being the target strings you want.

---

The simplest regex that *matches* your string is:

```
^(?i)a-([\\da-z]+)&b-(\\d+)&c-(\\d+)
```

With your target strings in groups 1, 2 and 3, but you need lot of code around that to get you the strings, which as shown above is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is very opt for my usecase

Answer (score 2):

you can use this pattern :

```
^(?i)a-([0-9a-z]++)&b-([0-9]++)&c-([0-9]++)$
```

In the case what you try to match is not the whole string, just remove the anchors:

```
(?i)a-([0-9a-z]++)&b-([0-9]++)&c-([0-9]++)
```

explanations:

```
(?i)         make the pattern case-insensitive 
[0-9]++      digit one or more times (possessive)
[0-9a-z]++   the same with letters 

^   anchor for the string start
$   anchor for the string end
```

Parenthesis in the two patterns are capture groups (to catch what you want)

Comment: +1, but why the possessive quantifiers? There's no possibility of catastrophic backtracking here.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will help you:

```
String[] texts = new String[]{"a-90485jlkerj&b-34534534&c-643546", "A-RT7456ffgt&B-86763454&C-684241"};
Pattern full = Pattern.compile("^(?i)a-([\\da-z]+)&b-(\\d+)&c-(\\d+)");
Pattern patternA = Pattern.compile("(?i)([\\da-z]+)&[bc]");
Pattern patternB = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
for (String text : texts) {
            if (full.matcher(text).matches()) {
                for (String part : text.split("-")) {
                    Matcher m = patternA.matcher(part);
                    if (m.matches()) {
                        System.out.println(part.substring(m.start(), m.end()).split("&")[0]);
                    }
                    m = patternB.matcher(part);
                    if (m.matches()) {
                        System.out.println(part.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```